# Unable to connect to Mysql programatically

Tags: c#, mysql, command-line, putty

I can successfully connect to a remote Mysql database through Putty, MySQL Workbench etc but am unable to within c#. The relevant code section is below.

Please note: The code previous to these calls opens a valid putty tunnel that I have tested to work correctly.

```
string dbhost = "localhost";
               string dbuser = "username";
               string dbpass = "userpwd";
               string dbdatabase = "valid_db";
               //string connStr = String.Format("server={0};user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false", dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbdatabase);
               string connStr = String.Format("server={0}; database={1}; user id={2}; password={3}; pooling=false", dbhost, dbdatabase, dbuser, dbpass);
               // Create a MySql Connection
               conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
               conn.Open();
```

Each and every time I try this I get the following error:
"Authentication to host 'localhost' for user 'username' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Access denied for user 'username'@'www.whatever..' (using password: YES)"

Any ideas appreciated as I have run out of searches to do to rectify this.

Answer (score 1):

read the documentation it might be useful: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html

Comment: Thanks for that but already tried what is listed there inclusive of different connection string and error handling etc